# JSON string output parameter from SQL Server stored procedure works in SSMS but produces empty value in C# client

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In my stored procedure, I've declared an OUTPUT parameter called `@Stats`:

```
@Stats nvarchar(max) OUTPUT
```

At the end of my stored procedure, I assign the results of a JSON query to the output parameter:

```
SELECT @Stats = (SELECT * FROM JsonStats FOR JSON AUTO)
```

If I execute the stored procedure in SSMS, I get the JSON data back from `@Stats` as expected:

```
DECLARE @Param1 nvarchar(max) = '...'
DECLARE @Stats nvarchar(max)

EXEC MySP @Param1, @Stats OUTPUT

SELECT @Stats
```

However, when I execute the stored procedure from C# code, I get an empty string back:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MySP", conn)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

var inputParam = new SqlParameter("@Param1", invoiceKeyListJson);
cmd.Parameters.Add(inputParam);

var outputParam = new SqlParameter("@Stats", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParam);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string statsJson = outputParam.Value.ToString();
```

After running the above code, `statsJson` is empty. The weird thing is, if I hard code the assignment of `@Stats` to an arbitrary string in the stored procedure, `statsJson` is assigned that value.

Why the inconsistency in results between SSMS and C#?  What do I need to do to get the JSON data back in C#?

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but you don't need to include the `EXEC` statement when setting `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`.

Comment: That was actually a mistake in pasting the code here -  the value comes from a variable so I added the string literal for clarity.  The actual code does not include "EXEC" and I have updated the question to reflect this.  Thanks!

Comment: what is type of @Param1 ?

Comment: nvarchar(max).  I have updated the question.

Comment: you are not passing the length of @Param1, that's why SQL could truncate your input and you wouldn't get the correct result.

Comment: Have you looked directly at outputParam after executing?

Comment: @SerkanArslan, specifying the length of \@Param1 makes no difference - I am still getting an empty string back.

Comment: @PaulGibson, yes  - Value={} and SqlValue={Null}.

Comment: In your stored procedure, could you try `SET @Stats = (SELECT * FROM JsonStats FOR JSON AUTO)` instead of `SELECT @Stats = (SELECT * FROM JsonStats FOR JSON AUTO)`

Comment: @AlistairFindlay, I get a syntax error when I use SET instead of SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by changing

```
SELECT @Stats = (SELECT * FROM JsonStats FOR JSON AUTO)
```

to:

```
SELECT @Stats = CAST((SELECT * FROM JsonStats FOR JSON AUTO) AS nvarchar(max))
```

(explicitly casting to `nvarchar(max)`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the size of your `outputParam` like so:

```
var outputParam = new SqlParameter("@Stats", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100000)
```